# Program Crash with CefSharp & Fastprox.dll

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

We have a new version of our app that we published out which utilizes CefSharp to serve up web pages for the user (the old version used the build-in .NET browser control).

Since upgrading, a handful of users have experienced random crashes that list the faulting module as `C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll`. They don't seem to be taking any particular actions when this occurs (in fact, some of them just have the program sitting idle) and it doesn't happen for every (or even most) users.

Unfortunately, the error details don't include any useful information except the faulting module (this comes from Event Viewer), and info on what exactly fastprox.dll does is scarce online. I've spent several hours combing through Google trying to find something to point me in the right direction - but nothing has helped so far.

At the moment, I'm not even sure where to start troubleshooting this, since we can't replicate it reliably. Any info on fastprox.dll or how it interacts with CefSharp would be greatly appreciated, as would any suggestions on troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Your question has a lot of words, very little technical details. CefSharp version, .Net version, operation system, WinForms, Wpf, x64, x86. What's different to the machines that work? If there is a event viewer entry there is likely a crash dump you can analyze. I've never heard of fastprox or seen anyone else having problems in the context of CefSharp. You'll have to do some low level debugging to find out what's going on.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#loading-native-symbols-for-easier-diagnosis

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the suggestions from that link a shot.